# Youtube API get original file

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there any way using the Youtube API to obtain the original file that the user uploaded to youtube?

In my application, I need this original file.  I could upload using direct method and keep a copy locally, then upload to youtube, but I was wondering if I could use browser-based upload method and still have access to the original.  I need the original file, not some high definition version of youtube or something similar.

Thanks,